# How to count number of days between events in a dataset

Tags: r, if-statement, count

I'm trying to restructure my data to recode a variable ('Event') so that I can determine the number of days between events. Essentially, I want to be able to count the number of days that occur between events occuring Importantly, I only want to start the 'count' between events after the first event has occurred for each person. Here is a sample dataframe:

```
Day = c(1:8,1:8)
Event = c(0,0,1,NA,0,0,1,0,0,1,NA,NA,0,1,0,1)
Person = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
sample <- data.frame(Person,Day,Event);sample
```

I would like it to end up like this:

```
NewEvent = c(NA,NA,0,1,2,3,0,1,NA,0,1,2,3,0,1,0)
sample2 <- sample <- data.frame(Person,Day,NewEvent);sample2
```

I'm new to R, unfamiliar with loops or if statements, and I could not find a thread which already answered this type of issue, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding the question. When you say calculate the number o days that occur between the events, do you mean between event 0 and event 1 and event NA? also, does each "person" represent an individual? if so, why dont you use name?

Comment: MKR addressed my issue. To clarify I was trying to count the number of days between events (i.e. when Event = 1). The count would continue even for days in which the value for Event is NA. And yes, "Person" refers to a Participant ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to group on `Person` and calculate distinct occurrence of events by `cumsum(Event == 1)`. Now, group on both `Person` and `grp` to count days passed from occurrence of distinct event. The solution will be as :

```
library(dplyr)

sample %>% group_by(Person) %>%
  mutate(EventNum = cumsum(!is.na(Event) & Event == 1)) %>%
  group_by(Person, EventNum) %>%
  mutate(NewEvent = ifelse(EventNum ==0, NA, row_number() - 1)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(Person, Day, NewEvent) %>%
  as.data.frame()


#    Person Day NewEvent
# 1       1   1       NA
# 2       1   2       NA
# 3       1   3        0
# 4       1   4        1
# 5       1   5        2
# 6       1   6        3
# 7       1   7        0
# 8       1   8        1
# 9       2   1       NA
# 10      2   2        0
# 11      2   3        1
# 12      2   4        2
# 13      2   5        3
# 14      2   6        0
# 15      2   7        1
# 16      2   8        0
```

**Note:** If data is not `sorted` on `Day` then one should add `arrange(Day)` in above code.

Comment: MKR - I was wondering if there is an easy way to restructure the variable (NewEvent) not in ascending order like your solution, but in descending order? So NewEvent = c(NA,NA,0,3,2,1,0,1,NA,0,3,2,1,0,1,0)

Comment: @leary9009 Yes. You can simple change the line with `ifelse` as `mutate(NewEvent = ifelse(EventNum ==0, NA, n() - row_number()))` and it will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks again! Your suggestion didn't quite work for me, but I got it to work for my purposes by making one small change to your code:

mutate(NewEvent = ifelse(EventNum ==0, NA, n() - (row_number()-1))) %>%

This results in the following: NewEvent = c(NA,NA,4,3,2,1,2,1,NA,4,3,2,1,2,1,1)

It doesn't reset the counter for NewEvent to 0 when Event=1, but for my needs this didn't matter.